# If sentence construction

Tags: conditionals

I want to use an "if sentence" in order to describe what could happen if my grandmother did not do something, but I'm struggling to do it.

What I came up with is:

> If my grandmother did not do the surgery, she would not be able to walk until today

What are the errors in this sentence, and how can I phrase it correctly?

Comment: Your intended meaning is unclear. I think you want to say: _If my grandmother had not had surgery, she would not be able to walk today_. The word _until_ in your sentence confuses the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an instance where the passive voice is useful.

The meaning of your sentence implies that your grandmother performed the surgery herself.

Better might be:

> If my grandmother did not *undergo* the surgery, she would not be able to walk today.

Comment: I don't think that's a passive construction.

Comment: As @Xanne implies, you're confusing the passive voice (If my grandmother had not been operated on) with an experiential verb (in the active voice). With 'She underwent the surgery' and 'She was operated upon', the grammar involved is different even though the semantics correspond closely. // 'If my grandmother had not had the operation (/ had not undergone the surgery), she would not be able to walk today' is a far more likely rewrite.